# Formulating in Assignment Problem

Tags: tables, matrices

[image: .]

```
        \label{T3}
        \[
        \begin{array}{c| c c c c|}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & M_1 & M_2 & M_3 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{M_4}\\ \cline{2-5}
            J_1 & 0 & 0.66 & 2 & 0.33\\
            J_2 & 1 & 0 & 1.22 & 0.33\\
            J_3 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
            J_4 & 2.33 & 0.33 & 1.67 & 0\\
            \cline{2-5}
        \end{array}
        \]
    \end{table}
```

[image: .]
please provide me with the latex formula for the assignment table which has a line like the image above

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

With use of the `nicematrix` and `tikz` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{NiceMatrix}
        & M_1   & M_2 & M_3     & M_4   \\
    J_1 & 0     & 0.66  & 2     & 0.33  \\
    J_2 & 1     & 0     & 1.22  & 0.33  \\
    J_3 & 0     & 1     & 2     & 1     \\
    J_4 & 2.33  & 0.33  & 1.67  & 0     \\
\CodeAfter
\tikz{
    \node (f) [draw, inner xsep=1em, fit=(2-2) (5-5)] {};
    \draw[line width=3pt, opacity=0.2]
        (2-2 |- f.north) -- (5-2 |- f.south)
        (3-2 -| f.west)  -- (3-5 -| f.east)
        (5-2 -| f.west)  -- (5-5 -| f.east);
     }
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

After two compilations you will get:

[image]

Comment: In answer is used `nicematrix` version 5.5!

Comment: sorry, in TeXstudio dont have ```nicematrix```

Comment: TeXstudio have/contain any package or LaTeX installation, it is just a editor, isn't it? See https://www.texstudio.org/. You need to install it with tools which is part of your LaTeX installation or do this manually (package is available on CTAN).

Comment: to use TeXstudio, I downloaded mikTeX as a packing from LaTex

Comment: Than use MikTeX Console utility and by 'packages' load missed package(s). Just now is availabel `nicematrix 7 version 5.6 :-)

Comment: So, what should I do? I do not understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116092/discussion-between-john-person-and-zarko).

Comment: Got `start` find `miktex`. i contain icon named `MikTeX Console` (admin ad user)t. Open it and find in it `package`. Click on it will open window with list of all packages. in list find `nicematrix` and than click on + sign. Thats is all.